# Cannot find which file represents the library you need to link

Tags: c, gcc

I have built and install code to my directory /usr/local/lib:

ls /usr/local/lib:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Apr  9 13:04 LibreSSL
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root      4096 Mar 20 09:54 netscape
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Apr  9 20:06 pkgconfig
drwxrwsr-x 4 root staff     4096 Dec 28 21:56 python2.7
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff     4096 Oct 17 09:24 python3.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21403926 Apr  8 18:05 libcrypto.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       969 Apr  8 18:05 libcrypto.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 Apr  8 18:05 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.46.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        19 Apr  8 18:05 libcrypto.so.46 -> libcrypto.so.46.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10741400 Apr  8 18:05 libcrypto.so.46.0.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4714494 Apr  8 18:05 libssl.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       976 Apr  8 18:05 libssl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 Apr  8 18:05 libssl.so -> libssl.so.48.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 Apr  8 18:05 libssl.so.48 -> libssl.so.48.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2219448 Apr  8 18:05 libssl.so.48.0.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    870622 Apr  8 18:05 libtls.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      1001 Apr  8 18:05 libtls.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 Apr  8 18:05 libtls.so -> libtls.so.20.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 Apr  8 18:05 libtls.so.20 -> libtls.so.20.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    433640 Apr  8 18:05 libtls.so.20.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       958 Apr  9 20:06 libwolfssl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 Apr  9 20:06 libwolfssl.so -> libwolfssl.so.24.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 Apr  9 20:06 libwolfssl.so.24 -> libwolfssl.so.24.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    473280 Apr  9 20:06 libwolfssl.so.24.0.0
```

I want to use `hmac.h` from wolfssl. However, when I run `gcc -L/usr/local/lib -o my_hmac_test my_hmac_test.c -lwolfssl` the code builds with a warning that address later:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/types.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/include/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/hash.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/include/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/hmac.h:31,
                 from my_hmac_test.c:1:
/usr/local/include/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:2053:14: warning: #warning "For timing resistance / side-channel attack prevention consider using harden options" [-Wcpp]
 2053 |             #warning "For timing resistance / side-channel attack prevention consider using harden options"
      |              ^~~~~~~
```

However, when I run the code. I get this error:

```
./my_hmac_test: error while loading shared libraries: libwolfssl.so.24: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

strace -f -e open gcc -L/usr/local/lib -o my_hmac_test my_hmac_test.c -lwolfssl:

```
strace: Process 32629 attached
In file included from /usr/local/include/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/types.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/include/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/hash.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/include/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/hmac.h:31,
                 from my_hmac_test.c:1:
/usr/local/include/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:2053:14: warning: #warning "For timing resistance / side-channel attack prevention consider using harden options" [-Wcpp]
 2053 |             #warning "For timing resistance / side-channel attack prevention consider using harden options"
      |              ^~~~~~~
[pid 32629] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32629, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=2, si_stime=1} ---
strace: Process 32630 attached
[pid 32630] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32630, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
strace: Process 32631 attached
strace: Process 32632 attached
[pid 32632] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 32631] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32632, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=1, si_stime=1} ---
[pid 32631] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SI
```

Comment: Seems odd. Run `strace -f -e open gcc -L/usr/local/lib -o my_hmac_test my_hmac_test.c -lwolfssl 2>&1 | grep libwolfssl` and see what GCC is trying to open when it says that it does not find the library. Also, you might want to use `pkg-config --cflags libwolfssl`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks. I've added that output, above.

Comment: Also check `/etc/ld.so.conf` and ensure `/usr/local/lib` is included, either directly or through an `include` statement. Otherwise you will have trouble finding the library.

Comment: Oh, the error is at runtime... sorry, didn't notice. Run *your* program with `strace` after compiling: `strace -f -e open,openat ./my_hmac_test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler warning you have observed is unrelated to the runtime loader
failure.

> I have built and install code to my directory /usr/local/lib

After you have placed any new shared library in any of the linker's default search
directories you must run:

```
ldconfig
```

as root, to update the OS loader's database of system libraries. Otherwise,
at runtime, the loader will remain unaware of the new library. You haven't
actually finished installing the new library until you have done this.
If you don't do it, then you will be obliged to use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` hack
that you discovered.

See [man ldconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig)

Answer (score 1):

Entered into my terminal `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` and ran `gcc -L/usr/local/lib -o my_hmac_test my_hmac_test.c -lwolfssl` from that same terminal. I should add the export line to my .bashrc now.